# VSCode intellisense doesn't work with ES6 import?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm stucking with this trouble for days.

`import abc from './abc'` doesn't work, the `abc.xyz()` or any function inside it will not be suggested.
Even the file `abc.js` will not be suggested

I have to use `abc = required('./abc.js')` and things work fine.
Both file suggestion and method will be available

I've tried to added `jsconfig.json` and force it to use `"module":"es6"` but didn't work either.

Already got `react native tools` installed.
Couldn't get it work eventually.

**Edit:**
i found out that `module.exports = User` doesn't work anymore. I have to write `export default User` if i want to access to all the method, since when and how to get old school export works?

Comment: What language do you see at the bottom right side of vs code?

Comment: @supra28 javascript, of course.

Comment: try setting it to JavaScript React instead and also if you have Babel Javascript extension installed disable that.

Comment: @supra28 i don't have Babel js extension installed, already changed it to `JavaScript React` but still doesn't work

Comment: wierd , try setting "module":"system" for your compilerOptions in jsconfig if es6 does't work

Comment: actually you should use target and not module if you are not using typescript

Comment: @supra28 i get the error after using `system` : `[js] Argument for '--target' option must be: 'es3', 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'es2018', 'esnext'.`

Comment: What does the files `abc` look like. How does it define the default export?

Comment: @MattBierner i found out that `module.exports = User` doesn't work anymore. I have to write `export default User` if i want to access to all the method, since when and how to get old school export work?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also experience the same issue when I `export default obj` where `obj` is `const = { a: 123, b: 456}`. It does not get autocompleted if I `import obj from 'obj.js'` and then `obj.<I type here and see nothing...>`

Answer (score 2):

Change your jsconfig.json to

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

and then you might need to restart VScode

the option module is used for typescript, more on this [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)

Comment: Can you post more info about this? Does this happen in all the projects? or just this one? Do you use typeScript? Did you try disabling all your extensions?

Comment: All project, i don't use typeScript, only react native and js. I've tried to disabled all extensions except `react native tools`. Got exactly error this guy have https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34342
The things is while i use `import`, it can't detect or suggest the js file like using `require`, so i think somehow Vscode couldn't read the file content needed for intellisense while using `import`

Comment: Oh, i found out that `module.exports = User` doesn't work anymore. I have to write `export default User` if i want to access to all the method, since when and how to get old school export work?